# how to get the object from the window.open in window.opener in chrome

Tags: javascript, window.open, window.opener

hi i am not able to get the object which i am passing through window.open

```
      var obj= new Object();
     var newpage= '';
    var urlaspx= "urlaspx.aspx?sid=1&frameWidth=" + frameWidth;

newpage= window.open(urlaspx, obj, 'center:yes; dialogWidth:400px; dialogHeight:430px; help:0; 
  status:0; scroll:0; resizable:1');
```

in my urlaspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var obj= window.opener;
var name= obj.name;
var age= obj.age;
</script>
```

here the obj object is null
pls help me on this

Answer (score 0):

The second argument for window.open should be a string, for the new window name, not an object.

I don't think browsers allow you to pass data from one window to another like that. (cf. [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

If you are the owner of both pages, you could add some parameters to the second page URL to pass data from one window to the other (like you do already for `frameWidth`).

```
const urlaspw = "urlaspx.aspx?"
  + "sid=1"
  + "&frameWidth=" + frameWidth
  + "&name=" + obj.name
  + "&age=" + obj.age;
const newpage = window.open(urlaspx, obj, 'center:yes; dialogWidth:400px; dialogHeight:430px; help:0; status:0; scroll:0; resizable:1');
```

```
    var obj = {};
    var currentLocation = window.location.toString()
    // or
    var currentSearch = window.location.search

    var params = currentSearch
      .split('?')[1]
      .split('&')
      .forEach(param => {
          obj[param.split('=')[0]] = param.split('=')[1]
       })
    var name = obj.name;
    var age = obj.age;
```

Comment: passed parameters with framewidth.but popup getting error that time.i have to get n number of properties so sending through url is not possible